# sorts in python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and get good at algorithms. This is my first language.

for example: take "baggage" and sort into "aabeggg"

```
string = "baggage"
count = [0] * len(string)

for x in string:
    num_value = ord(x)
    count[num_value] += 1
```

I think the above is a start...but I'm not really sort how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collections.Counter` is a great way to solve this, but here is a way to get you a bit further in the direction you are heading

```
string = "baggage"
count = [0] * 256  # This should be big enough to hold counters for every 8 bit character

for x in string:
    num_value = ord(x)
    count[num_value] += 1

for i in range(256):  # loop through all the possible 8 numbers
    if count[i]: 
        print chr(i)*count[i]

# you can join them all back into a string like this
newstr = ''.join(chr(i)*c for i,c in enumerate(count))
```

Comment: I like that this solution avoids calling `sorted`.  This seems to be much closer to what OP intended.

Comment: `''.join(chr(i) * c for i, c in enumerate(count))` your current version doesn't call `chr` and I like `enumerate`.

Comment: @agf, thanks. fixed and i agree enumerate looks nicer. I'll leave the loop without it as it is less for the OP to take in at once

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your code here.

```
string = "baggage"
count = [0] * len(string)
# count is now [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for x in string:
    num_value = ord(x)
    # ord(x) gives you the ascii number value of a character x
    # So for example ord('b') = 98
    count[num_value] += 1
    # error here since count[98] isn't set.
```

Pablo gave you a quick solution. I'll write out one using a dictionary that might be more explicit.

```
string = "baggage"
count = {}

for c in string:
    if c in count:
        count[c] += 1
    else:
        count[c] = 1

print ''.join(count[c]*c for c in sorted(count))
```

Comment: But then you're just getting an array of 1's. Each `index` value appears only once in the `range` (or `enumerate`).

Comment: @Pablo Yeah, I tried to clarify that I'm not entirely sure what the objective is. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, or maybe `count` is a misleading name.

Comment: He's trying to count the number of appearances of each char to then build the string of sorted chars.

Comment: @Omerta Okay, I've edited my answer. Hopefully this is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
string = 'baggage'
c = Counter(string)
result = ''.join(c[x]*x for x in sorted(c.keys()))
```

It works as follows:

- `Counter` does exactly what you were trying to achieve with `count[num_value] += 1`
- `sorted(c.keys())` gives you the characters in sorted order
- `c[x]*x` is a string made up of `c[x]` copies of the char `x`
- `''.join( ... )` joins each of the resulting strings into a single one